# Make jQuery Search Filter use a Data attribute instead of whole DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a KanBan board style app that shows Order records.  I am trying to implement a Search filter using JavaScript and jQuery.  THe goal is to filter out and hide all records that do not match the search number with the Order Number on a record.

So far I have a working example however I feel it can be improved possibly?

Here is my working JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/d7hj0ssv/1/

So basically it;s very simple....

1. It when the search form is submitted, it hides all Order records
2. It then uses this line `$('.box:contains("'+txt+'")').show();` where `txt` is the search term.  So after hiding all records, it `display: block` on any DIVs that match the search term.

`$('.box:contains("'+txt+'")')` is where my concern is.  I believe it searches the whole entire Order record DIV for a matching string?

Each Order DIV looks like this code below so `$('.box:contains("'+txt+'")')` is searching this whole entire block of content for each order I believe which just looks bad performance wise!...

```
<div class="box card-record ui-sortable-handle" data-order-id="5430" data-order-number="100005054" data-order-item-id="145" style="display: block;">
    <div class="alert-message warning">

        <div class="ordernumber">Order #100005054</div>
        <div class="orderid">Order ID: 5430</div>
        <div class="itemid">Item #145</div>
        <div>Date Created: 2015-06-23 00:27:22</div>
        <div>Date Modified: 2015-06-23 00:27:22</div>
        <div>some order data here</div>

        <a href="#" data-order-id="5430" data-order-item-id="145" data-url="/orders/orderboards/order/item/145" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default openmodal">View Order Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**In the DIV HTML above you might notice that each Order record also has a data attribute `data-order-number="100005054"` which I think might be better to use for the search if possible?**

---

Below is my jQuery JavaScript code that handles the Search input and filtering out the DIVs based on the search term:

```
$(function() {

    // Search filter to hide and show order cards mtching the search order number
    $('#search').click(function(){
        $('.box').hide();
        var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
        $('.box:contains("'+txt+'")').show();
    });

    $('#searchclear').click(function(){
        $('.box').show();
        $('#search-criteria').val('');
    });

});
```

Comment: **each Order record also has a data attribute**: Not sure about the performance, but `$('.box[data-order-number*="'+txt+'"]')` is how you select `.box` with attribute `data-order-number` that contains `txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search field is the `order-number` then yes, using the data-attribute would greatly improve your apps response time. You would use the jQuery `.filter(function)` method:

```
$('#search').on('click', function() {
    $('.box').hide().filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('order-number') == $('#search-criteria').val().trim();
    }).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d7hj0ssv/3/)

Comment: Thanks I was interested in experimenting with the `filter` function so I will try this out as well!

Comment: NP. You'll find it very handy.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make it do partial search matches?  FOr example the search result for `100005081` matches that record now but if they had only `10000508` missing the last number it would still match?  Not super important but curious

Comment: Sure ... use `return ..data('order-number').indexOf( txt ) > -1;`.

Comment: I never could get your last comment working but I selected your answer for the other demo

Comment: The `.toString()` method is required to turn the number into a string as number does not have `.indexOf()`. Sorry about that .... see http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/d7hj0ssv/5/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target the div with that `data`, you can use the attribute selector syntax. This isn't terribly performant, but it *should* be faster than the `:contains` pseudo selector.

```
$('.box[data-order-number="'+txt+'"]').show();
```

or

```
$('.box[data-order-id="'+txt+'"]').show();
```

Some of your elements don't seem to have `data-order-number` in the fiddle, so I've used the id for the example. Not sure on the specifics between the two.

http://jsfiddle.net/47m7p2am/

---

The other option is to generate unique IDs or shared classes.

```
id="order-number-100005054" class="order-id-5418"
```

This would be much faster to look up, and the ideal solution if you can edit the HTML output.

Something like:

```
$('#order-number-' + txt).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solutions and yes I can alter the HTML so I might try out the ID method

Comment: IDs will be *really* fast, but make sure that theres only one element with a given ID on the page.